# creating multiline field in page property using CSOM

Tags: 2013, 2010

I want to add a multiline text field to a page property using CSOM

```
string schemaRichTextField = "<Field ID='<GUID>' Type='Note' Name='Comments' StaticName='Comments'
DisplayName='Comments' NumLines='6'  RichText='TRUE' Sortable='FALSE' />" 
Field multilineTextField = demoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaRichTextField , true, AddFieldOptions.AddInternalNameHint);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It adds the multiline field, but how can I make it allow unlimited lenght?

Comment: In a list or library?

Comment: in library @AtishDipongkor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlimited length is only supported in Library not in list. From one of my library, I picked up a multi line column. I found the following `SchemaXml`

```
<Field Type="Note" DisplayName="MultiPLe" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE" NumLines="6" Sortable="FALSE" ID="{d89f2e79-4025-4eaa-9e56-53bfef726091}" SourceID="{63ff3aad-360b-4484-aade-283e603a975e}" StaticName="MultiPLe" Name="MultiPLe" ColName="ntext3" RowOrdinal="0" Version="1" />"
```

So comparing it with your `SchemaXml`, I found `UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE"` is missing in your `SchemaXml`.

Comment: thanks @atish. I was exactly looking for `UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary`